# Need help styling the user-inputs from a form that uses javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm really new to javascript. I'm doing an assignment that requires me to create a madlibs game where the words that are supplied by the user show up in the story. I'm having difficulty making the user-supplied words appear as a different color within the actual story. What is necessary to do that?

this is the js, css, and html.

```js
// Step 1 Found the element I want the event on
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  // Step 2 Defined the event listener function
  var onButtonClick = function() {
       var place = document.getElementById("place").value;
  var noun = document.getElementById("noun").value;
  var songtitle = document.getElementById("songtitle").value;
  var verb = document.getElementById("verb").value;
       
document.getElementById("story").textContent += "The people of " + place + " lost their princess to the wind. She blew away so far she had no idea where she was. The land was made of " +  noun + " and the clouds looked like  " + noun + ". A band of " + noun  + " played her favorite song, " + songtitle + ". They " + verb + " and " + verb + " until she fell asleep" +  ". She woke up on a "  + noun + " and realized she never left " + place + " and was only dreaming. " ;  
  };
  // Step 3 Attach event listener to element
  button.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
```

```css
body {
   background-color: #e03845;
      }

form {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 2em;
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-radius: 1em;
      }

h1 { 
 font-family: PT Sans;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 color: #d0ddf7;
 
 }
      
div { 
 padding: .2em;
 text-align: center;
 color: black;

 }
 
#button {
 padding: 2em;
 }
 
#story {

 color: black;
 font-family: PT Sans bold;
 font-size: 20px ;
 
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Katherine's Mad Princess Fairy Tale</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <form>
  <h1>Mad Libs</h1>
        <div>
          <label for="Place">Place:</label> <input type="text" id="place"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="Noun">Noun:</label> <input type="text" id="noun"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="Song Title">Song Title:</label> <input type="text"   
          id="songtitle"></textarea>
          </div>
        <div>
          <label for="Verb">Verb (past tense):</label> <input type="text"     
          id="verb"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="button">
          <button type="button">Tell Story</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <br/>
    <form>
    <h1>Katherine's Mad Princess Fairy Tale</h1>
 <div id="story"></div>
    <script src="madlibs.js" script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </form>    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you wrap your injected words in an html tag, you can style that. That's pretty much it. You'll need to use innerHTML or something rather than textContent for that to work though.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("story").textContent += "The people of <span class=\"madlibword\">" + place + "<\/span> lost their princess to the wind. She blew away so far she had no idea where she was. The land was made of <span class=\"madlibword\">" +  noun "+ "<\/span>" ;
```

and a css class

```
.madlibword{color:purple;}
```